# What is difference between USER defined in Dockerfile and runAsUser defined in deployment file of Kubernetes?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have some confusions about user defined in Docker file and in Kubernetes environment.

- What if we have defined different user in docker file and in deployment file. Which user will be running the application in the container.
- If we have not defined user in deployment file, will it run the pod container as user defined in Dockerfile.
- If we have not defined any user in Dockerfile and in deployment file, Does it mean our services will be running as root user.
- Can we provide valid random UUID in Kubernetes deployment yaml file. And if this user is not present in the image, Kubernetes creates it automatically and run the service with that user.

Answer (score 0):

> What if we have defined different user in docker file and in deployment file. Which user will be running the application in the container.

The one from deployment.

> If we have not defined user in deployment file, will it run the pod container as user defined in Dockerfile.

Yes.

> If we have not defined any user in Dockerfile and in deployment file, Does it mean our services will be running as root user.

Yes (unless any base image specifies some other user).

> Can we provide valid random UUID in Kubernetes deployment yaml file. And if this user is not present in the image, Kubernetes creates it automatically and run the service with that user.

No. Kubernetes does not mess with container contents. If you want it like that - you must program that in your image.